# Derivation of Hartree-Fock equations using 2nd quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, perturbation-theory, second-quantization

I derived the following effective Hamiltonian:

$$ H_{eff} = \sum_k{ \left( \, \epsilon_k + \sum_{k_2}{\left(<k \, |<k_2 \, |\,u\,| \, k_2>|\, k> 
- <k\,|<k_2\,|\,u\,|\,k>|\,k_2>\right)} <c_{k_2}^+c_{k_2}>_{eff} \, \right) c_k^+c_k } \qquad $$

Where $u = \frac{e^2}{r_i-r_j}$. I derived the equation above in a Hartree-Fock approximation and now i want to derive the following equation:

$$ \epsilon_k | \, k > + \sum_{k_2}{(<k_2 \, |\,u\,| \, k_2>|\, k> - <k_2\,|\,u\,|\,k>|\,k_2>)} = \tilde{\epsilon_k} |\, k >
$$

However I have no idea how to?

Can someone give me some advices please.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: It is not a homework. I am reading a book in condensed matter physics and I try to derive the Hartree-Fock equations but I simply don't understand the last step

Comment: The way you have phrased your question follows our definition of homework-like questions (cf. the first link I provided). Note also that questions asking for derivations are [also considered off-topic](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5968/25301) (though I'm sure plenty of people contest this & don't vote to close such questions).

Comment: If it helps, here, in Appendix A is A derivation of Hartree-Fock in 2nd quantization.

https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/_static/rostgaard_master.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a Variation Problem and I have to calculate the following:

$$ \delta (<  \phi_{eff}| H_{eff}-E |\phi_{eff}> )=0 $$

Therefore it is straightfoward.